# Display Parse Device Token to User

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've got Parse set up all good and a device token appears in the Control Panel of Parse. Now what I need to figure out is how to display the device token on the device screen. They're iOS devices so all Obj-C. I just need a button that says "Token" and on the screen appears the string, nothing fancy. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Ed

Comment: Put the token string into a UILabel?  I am not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

NSString *string = [currentInstallation objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];

yourLabel.text = string;
```

Comment: Where abouts do I put this? The .h or .m? I've created the xib file and made my design but I have a limited knowledge of Obj-C and used Buzztouch to create my app. I just need to create this screen... can you tell me where to put this and what to do with the PFInstallation etc..?

Comment: @EdG Yes if you have your label hooked up through an iboutlet you can just put this in the .m file

Comment: Ok so I know less than I thought... how to I hook it up through an iboutlet?

Comment: @EdG control drag the label to your .h file

Comment: I've dragged that in now and got IBOutlet UILabel *lblDeviceToken; - that looks alright. Now what do I modify in the code? Sorry I know it must be really annoying trying to help over the comments!

Comment: @EdG just change the label name to whatever you named it in your header, copy and paste the code I went you, and make sure you imported the parse framework to those files

Comment: How do I change the name? Complete novice now! And is this in the AppDelegate?

Comment: @EdG Copy and paste my code into your view controller .m file. Then change my code to lblDeviceToken instead of yourLabel

Comment: Thanks for the help so far - got a few errors after doing that... https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn3a8cta6k41ot3/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-02%20at%2019.55.22.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1hbxii18vqb23e/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-02%20at%2019.55.33.png?dl=0 - any ideas?

Comment: @EdG Change the code in the .m file to self.lblDeviceToken

Comment: doesn't seem to have done anything https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvith7021c8s7zu/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-02%20at%2019.59.47.png?dl=0 - now got this

Comment: The only one I have, viewDidLoad

Comment: Wait, looks like it is working now. Moved it to a different place in the method.

Comment: The token is quite big for the screen! Is there any way to generate a Barcode or QR code to display underneath the UILabel in the XIB file?